# Constructing foldl using foldr

Tags: haskell

I am trying to create `foldl` using `foldr` (a good exercise to learn haskell, and the other SO answers seem to complex).

My solutions is this:

```
myFoldl :: (b -> a -> b) -> [a] -> (b -> b)
myFoldl f = foldr op z
  where
    z = []
    op x xs b = myFoldl f xs (f b x)
```

but it does not work. I get an error saying:

```
• Couldn't match type ‘a -> b’ with ‘[a]’
  Expected type: b -> (a -> b) -> a -> b
    Actual type: b -> [a] -> a -> b
• In the first argument of ‘foldr’, namely ‘op’
  In the expression: foldr op z
  In an equation for ‘myFoldl’:
      myFoldl f
        = foldr op z
        where
            z = []
            op x xs b = myFoldl f xs (f x b)
```

but it looks good to me. `myFoldl` takes a function, a list, and something to work with.  Why is this not working? (New to haskell, still trying to figure it all out).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you have:

```
myFoldl f = foldr op z
```

you must also have:

```
myFoldl f xs = foldr op z xs                  -- (**)
```

From the type of `myFoldl`, the LHS must have type `b -> b`.  On the other hand, from the type of `foldr`, the RHS has the same type as `z`, which you defined as `z = []` which has a list type, `[c]`.  So, this expression has type `b -> b` but also the list type `[c]`, and these two types cannot be reconciled.

The larger problem is that your `op` shouldn't be defined recursively in terms of `myFoldl`.  The point of the fold (whether left or right) is to *replace* the explicit recursion, abstracting away the recursion pattern as the fold definition, expressing it with the one-step recombination operation `op x r = ...` where `r` is the result for our problem's recursive sub-problem, already calculated for us by the fold itself.  A correct definition of the one-step recombination operation thus shouldn't involve any recursive definitions.

Sooooo, let me try to set you on the right track.  I think you've recognized that the defining recursive relationship for your `myFoldl` is:

```
myFoldl f (x:xs) b = myFoldl f xs (f b x)     -- (1a)
myFoldl f []     b = b                        -- (1b)
```

Using the definition (**) above, you want to reconcile it with the defining recursive relationship for `foldr`:

```
foldr op z (x:xs) = op x (foldr op z xs)
foldr op z []     = z
```

which we could eta abstract over `b` like so:

```
foldr op z (x:xs) b = op x (foldr op z xs) b  -- (2a)
foldr op z []     b = z b                     -- (2b)
```

Note that the only way (1b) and (2b) are going to give the same result is if `b` and `z b` are equal for all `b`.  Note that `z` is a function here, not a list!  Hopefully, you can immediately identify what function `z` needs to be here.

For reconciling (1a) and (2a), your solution was to write `op x xs b = myFoldl f xs (f b x)`, but that's not the right equation.  The correct equation, matching up the RHSs of (1a) and (2a) above is:

```
op x (foldr op z xs) b = myFoldl f xs (f b x)
```

and rewriting the `foldr` on the left in terms of our `myFoldl` using (**) up above, we get:

```
op x (myFoldl f xs) b = myFoldl f xs (f b x)
```

Now, can you see what non-recursive definition of the one-step recombination operation `op` would satisfy this equation?  (Hint: it's a very simple definition.)

```
op x r              b = ....
```